# How to compare the whole array for having same value

Tags: c#, .net

I am in the need of checking a string array for empty strings. That means the whole array contains only empty strings. Something like

```
String[] temp ;
temp got filled
if(temp == "" ) // Means every member is an empty string
    //do this
```

Can anybody say how to achieve this? Or is it possible?

**EDIT:**Looping is OK. But is there any way possible without looping?

Comment: even if you use LINQ there will be an iteration internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (temp.All(s => s == ""))
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return true if all elements of an array of strings are empty strings:

```
Array.TrueForAll(temp, s => s.Length == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Here you will get valid strings in res

```
string[] temp = new string[] { "", "abc", "axyz" }; 
var res= temp.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
if(res.Count()>0)
{
    .....//temp contains atleast one valid string
}

if(res.Count()==0)
{
    .....//All strings in temp are empty
}
```

for empty strings

```
var emptyStringsres= temp.Where(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.TruForAll method will do this.

```
String[] temp ;
temp got filled
if (Array.TrueForAll(temp, string.IsNullOrEmpty))
{
    //do this
}
```